# I need to display a different link for anonymous users and register users for same content

Tags: navigation

I have a webform containing a link. I want to change the link depending on the users accessing the webform.
For anonymous users, the link should point to user/register?destination=[current page]; for authenticated users, the link should point to form/event-registration.

Answer (score 0):

In `build > elements` you will need to create 2 `html markup` or `Advanced HTML/Text` elements

Each one will have the links mentioned 
[image]

There is a setting `access` that you can choose who has access to it

For the other link you can choose **anonymous** 
[image]

For one of the elements you will choose **authenticated**
[image]

If this solution is not satisfactory 100% you will need to override webform